# Problems with FromFormAttribute and deserialization in AspNet Core 3.1 Api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, deserialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I use Newtonsoft deserializer and try to send data(with FromFormAttribute) in this method:

```
[HttpPut("test")]
public IActionResult Test([FromForm] MyClass Test) {           
    return Ok();
}
```

also, I have class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Text { get; protected set; }

    public MyClass(int id, string text) {
        Id = id;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

When I try to send data in HttpPut method I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'MyClass'. 
Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.
Alternatively, give the 'test' parameter a non-null default value.
```

I didn't create a parameterless constructor and have protected setters because it works fine in other methods with FromBodyAttribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the constructor and `protected` keyword.

Comment: @arcticwhite it will work fine, but i must have protected properties and public ctor with parameters

Comment: Your error is saying that you must have parameterless constructor.

Comment: @arcticwhite excuse me, i don't understand you. I didn't say what i must have parameterless ctor. I just say i need public ctor with params and protected properties

Comment: Could we know the specific reason for that? We'll think a solution to have it protected and also have a constructor, but could we have more context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a parameterless constructor

```cs
 public class MyClass
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
            

            public MyClass()
            {
            }
            public MyClass(int id, string text)
            {
                Id = id;
                Text = text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: parametless ctor does not have to be public at all

Comment: it will serialize, but with default values: 0 for Id and null for Text

Comment: @zolty13 with protected ctror will deserializer error

Comment: @hernantos so what is the problem with default values? what do you want to do?
FromForm is not using your custom contractor